# Interference of orbital electron wavefunctions

Tags: wavefunction, atomic-physics, subatomic

Any electron in an atom is described as a standing wavefunction in a potential well. In multielectron atoms, when an electron in any orbital beyond 1S² is described, is it the resultant of interference of all other wavefunctions or is it calculated as if it's the sole electron in that atom?

Answer (score 0):

In principle it should be solved as a many-electron system, i.e. the electrons should be described by a joint wave function $\Psi_{s_1,...,s_N}(\mathbf{r}_1,...,\mathbf{r}_N)$. However, in practice the many-body problem is no less challenging in quantum mechanics than in classical one, so one would often use approximations, representing multi-electron states as *combinations* of single-electron orbitals. Since these belong to different electrons, there is no interference them, although they do need to be modified to accommodate the Pauli principle and the electron-electron Coulomb interactions.

Answer (score 0):

These are *different* electrons that are in *different* orbitals, all labelled by different quantum numbers and hence distinguishable. Therefore, they do not interfere.

You will still detect a higher charge density if you hover over at a position where more than one orbital has a maximum. But this is the result of the sum of the intensities $|\psi_1|^2 + |\psi_2|^2$ (incoherent) rather than sum of the wavefunctions (coherent -> interference) $|\psi_1 + \psi_2|^2$.